# Hidden Stack Snippets are not accessible and violate web standards

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets, accessibility

I noticed recently in a [question about accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192534/accessibility-using-media-queries-to-hide-text), that a snippet I included (marked as hidden by default; as it includes more details then strictly necessary for the question) is not very accessible. As an expandable item it should have an [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-expanded) or, better yet, be implemented with the semantically correct [`<details>` / `<summary>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

Comment: What about those poor people using IE and Edge that don't support `<details>`/`<summary>`?

Comment: @NickA There are [polyfills](https://github.com/javan/details-element-polyfill). Just make sure to pick one that implements [accessibility correctly](https://github.com/javan/details-element-polyfill/blob/master/src/index.js#L136-L145)

Comment: If those details that aren't being shown are so important, wouldn't that be an argument for not hiding them by default, instead? I'd argue it's working as intended: The author of the snippet deemed the snippet to be optional, so collapsed it by default.

Comment: @Cerbrus Whether this is implemented with the appropriate tags or with the `aria-expanded` attribute, doesn’t matter. As long they are made accessible.

Comment: @Cerbrus In the linked question the user was able to answer my question thoroughly without seeing the snippet in question. It was only in the comments where we were talking about the more nuanced details that they were missing information. I would say that is a just use of hidden by default. These are details that are not relevant to the immediate question, but might help expending on it.

Comment: I despise IE but @NickA has a point. Also, most projects can't just afford to abandon legacy browsers for the sake of web standards.

Comment: @LogicalBranch Nobody is talking about making this feature inaccessible for IE / Edge users. All we need to do is add the appropriate `aria` attributes on the controls and contents of the snippets. If we were going to use the semantically correct elements—which are currently not supported by all major browsers—we would surely include polyfills to support those as well.

Comment: **We're no longer accepting retags on this question.** The discussion about whether this should be tagged as [[meta-tag:bug]] or [[meta-tag:feature-request]] has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190735/discussion-on-question-by-runar-berg-hidden-stack-snippets-are-not-accessible-an). Conclusion: [[meta-tag:bug]]. If you want to discuss the matter further, ask a new question about it.